# Saltstack: How can I control the output of cmd.run?

Tags: saltstack

I am only using Saltstack to run commands on multiple servers, e.g. to check if a specific TYPO3 extension exists on any server. I want to suppress empty output of minions (i.e. the hostname) and want to see if a minion could not be reached.

Sample output of how it is at the moment:

```
serverA:

serverB:

serverC:
    /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/typo3conf/ext/news/ext_emconf.php:  'version' => '4.2.1',
serverD:
```

Sample output of how it should be (let's assume serverX is down):

```
serverC:
    /var/www/vhosts/example.com/httpdocs/typo3conf/ext/news/ext_emconf.php:  'version' => '4.2.1',
serverX: is down!
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use output in one line (`--out txt`)

`salt --out txt '*'  cmd.run 'if [ -f /tmp/xxx ];then echo 'hello';fi'`

will output if file exists:

`minion1: hello`

will output nothing if file doesn't exist